# Date range filter in where clause

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

```
select distinct username,type,datenumber,created,engagement
from table1 a
join table2 b 
on a.datenumber = b.datenumber and a.username=b.username
where engagement in (a.created - 1 year)
and datenumber >= 20151231;
```

I need something to get the logic of engagement in (a.created - 1 year).
I can do case when but it will be hardcoded, and everytime someone needs to add new when statement next year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BETWEEN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/r_range_condition.html) and [DATEADD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html)

```
SELECT distinct username,type,datenumber,created,engagement
from table1 a
join table2 b 
on a.datenumber = b.datenumber and a.username=b.username
where engagement BETWEEN a.created AND DATEADD(year,-1,a.created)
and datenumber >= 20151231;
```